# Postgres триггер по времени

Tags: postgresql

Могу ли я создать триггер, удаляющий таблицы с определенным именем (YYYY_MM_table), срабатывающий в начале каждого месяца?

Comment: А почему бы шедулер Pgagent Не использовать?

Comment: А как его использовать, не подскажите?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У PosgreSQL нет системного триггера, только триггеры на внешние действия. Используйте сторонние планировщики, например, Cron у Linux.